# why are images getting downloaded from my server when they say they're cached?

Tags: caching, laravel-7

I'm building a site with a lot of static images: they're drawings that I store as `/public_html/images/[uuid].png`. I expect my browser to download them only once, then use a cached version from that point on. What happens, however, is that the browser frequently downloads them.

I checked the headers of the network tab (making sure not to disable the cache there), and this is what I see:

[image]

Doesn't the `expires` attribute mean that a browser wouldn't have to download the file again for another month?

This isn't my area of expertise, so I don't really understand what's happening. Do I need some kind of `META` tag? Maybe I'm missing something in `.htaccess`? For what it's worth, I'm building the site using Laravel 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My new understanding is that everything is working as expected. I noticed that the images were being cached sometimes, (using memory, not the disk), so the headers weren't being misleading. The browser would pull the images from memory when possible, but if I closed the browser, it would forget them.

At first, I thought that my website was cool enough that the browser would store everything forever (up to the expiry date), but I realize now that if the browser stored everything it saw on the internet, then it would very quickly use a huge amount of disk space, and that's unreasonable.